# The Copyeditor's Handbook says this is not a suspended compound

Tags: punctuation

The Copyeditor's Handbook says:

In a phrase like

### "ten-to-fifteen-minute traffic delays," the "ten to fifteen" constitutes a unit — an approximation of length of the backup — and it is therefore not a suspended compound.

I was always taught to write it as:

ten- to fifteen-minute traffic delays
(with a space after the hyphen in 
"ten-").

Do you agree with The Copyeditor's Handbook with its version:
ten-to-fifteen-minute traffic delays?

Thank you.

Comment: What's a suspended compound, and what's the matter with it? Does it offend the Copyeditor God or something?

Comment: This handbook needs to be taken with a grain of salt. If you need to be governed by some outside ruling, follow it. Otherwise use your own judgment.

Comment: The Handbook of Good English agrees with this notion and says that "I bought ten- to twenty-year bonds" is wrong, because the compound is meant to indicate a range of bond maturities, not two separate bond categories, and it should be unified rather than suspended as in the following exemplar:

I bought ten-to-twenty-year bonds.

Do you agree with the example above with three hyphens?

Comment: In addition to *agree* / *disagree*, may we have a third choice: *‘don’t care’* (or *makes no difference*, if you want something gentler)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Speaking as a copy editor, I can assure you that Copyeditorism is a polytheistic faith. On the one hand, I see where *The Copyeditor's Handbook* is coming from. Its idea is that if you were to include the implied unit of measure after the first number, you wouldn't want to punctuate it this way:

> ten-minute to fifteen-minute traffic delays

because the result would be a strangely modular presentation that did a poor job of conveying the sense that the author was talking about a range. But on the other hand,

> ten-minute-to-fifteen-minute traffic delays

doesn't look so great either. And what if

> ten- to fifteen-minute traffic delays

is actually short for

> congestion that may result in anything from ten-minute traffic delays to fifteen-minute traffic delays

instead? In that case, it seems to me, "ten- to fifteen-minute traffic delays" does a better job of conveying the sense of the implied full wording, besides avoiding the appearance that half of your sentence is working on a chain gang.

By way of a counter-authority to *The Copyeditor's Handbook*, I offer *Chicago Manual of Style*, Fifteenth Edition (2003), at 7.89:

> **7.89** *Hyphen with word space.* When the second part of a hyphenated expression is omitted the hyphen is retained, followed by a word [i.e., letter] space.
>
> [Relevant examples:] five- to ten-minute intervals *but* a five-by-eight-foot rug (a single entity)

In my view, "ten- to fifteen-minute traffic delays" is a lot closer to "five- to ten-minute intervals" than to "a five-by-eight-foot rug." But I could live with either approach if it were imposed on me from above. In that respect, placating gods is not unlike placating authors: in some cases a pleasant task, in others a thankless one, and in still others quite impossible. I find solace in Robusto's advice (in a comment above) to use your own judgment unless forced not to—and in the consciousness that, if one god is frowning on your actions, another is probably smiling.

Comment: So, similarly, the same principle would very technically apply to these two examples: a $65,000- to $75,000-a-year savings;                         a $3 million- to $5 million-a-year contract. Hyphenation-wise, these need to be suspended too, with a space after the first hyphen in each. Agree to the punctuation in both?

Comment: The Chicago approach would lead to the treatment you specify in both of your examples; the Copyeditor's Handbook approach would lead to closed-up versions of each of those examples, with two fewer spaces and one more hyphen in each.

Comment: In other words, The Copyeditor's Handbook would do it like this, correct? a $65,000-to-$75,000-a-year savings; a $3 million-to-$5 million-a-year contract

Comment: Actually, I think that _The Copy Editor's Handbook_ might well come out in favor of "$3-million-to-$5-million-a-year," though I can't say for sure.

Comment: @SvenYargs: The latter example seems apt to be awkward or ambiguous no matter how one writes it, unless one can rephrase entirely, as something like "a contract between $3 million and $5 million."

Comment: @supercat: I agree. In fact, I  had the same feeling (though not as acutely) about every one of these examples. For a reader, "traffic delays of 10 to 15 minutes" is easier on the eyes than any of the hyphenated, front-loaded forms.

Comment: If you leave out the units from the first number, you could run into difficulties with something like "[the current mortality data are consistent with between 63 and 136,000 cases](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v406/n6796/full/406583a0.html)" and whether the first number is about half the second or less than a thousandth (the latter in this particular example)

Comment: If the intention was to have many orders of magnitude between the quantities, I would duplicate the word "cases".  If the difference was much smaller, I would say "between 63 and 136 thousand cases" or "between 63,000 and 136,000".  I would not regard groups of zeroes as a unit which may be elided when duplicated.